# Meteor.js - temporarily prevent a template from re-rendering (disable reactivity)

Tags: meteor

I have a page in my app with a list of Projects the user is working on.

When they want to add a new project, I show a modal form to get the name of the project.

If they click 'OK' I create the project and redirect to /project/[new project id] using Meteor.Router.

However, just before the redirect, I see the new project name automatically to the user's list of projects.

I want to avoid this unnecessary re-rendering, which causes a brief flash of updated content.

Is there a way to prevent the template for my list of projects from re-rendering?

Answer (score 4):

You can put your html containing this into a `{{#constant}}` block. [Docs on constant](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant)

e.g

```
{{#constant}}
    {{#each ...}}
    ....
    {{/each}}
{{/constant}}
```

Another option is to disable reactivity in your template helper e.g if you have

```
Template.home.mydata = function() { return MyCollection.find() }
```

change this to use `reactive:false` as an option

```
Template.home.mydata = function() { return MyCollection.find({}, {reactive:false}) }
```

This way the initial changes are shown but any updates aren't used so there wouldn't be a re-render.

Comment: That's close, but I want the template to be reactive the rest of the time (eg. if another user changes the name of a project, I want to see that change). I have a temporary workaround - redirect to a URL that shows a blank template before attempting to create the new project.

Comment: You can use reactive false/true to enable/disable it when you want. But the template will be re-rendered. Usually there isn't a flash or anything like that it changes the DOM directly. Are you using a submit button btw? You might not be using preventDefault

Comment: {{#constant}} is excellent for live search if you use a session variable, destroy, then rerender the template

Comment: {{#constant}} is just for not updating DOM, and as same as `find({}, {reactive:false})`. But actually in this case, before clicking 'OK' button, the project document should not be synced to server. Sorry I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: `{{#constant}}` is not supported anymore: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#no-more-constant-isolate-or-preserve

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using cancel inside the event handler after the call to the methods cancels the chain of reactivity.

```
Template.questionTeaser.events({
  "click .vote_add": function(event, template){
    Meteor.call('vote_add', this._id, this.session)

    // This cancels the chain of reactivity.
    return false
  },
})
```

I use it for the following use case:

Users sees a list of questions sorted by votes
User can upvote
After upvote the list gets rerendered/sorted BUT with a countdown in the rightside of the page so the user knows he cant click for a second.