# Prevent function from re-rendering template

Tags: javascript, web, meteor

Solved.
It turned out to be something else completely.
Thanks for everyone that tried to help, you guys rule!

Comment: show us code please :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a guess here but would need to see your code to make sure I'm giving you a good answer :-). You can't prevent a reactive data source from triggering an invalidation, but you can run some code in a nonreactive callback to make sure that code is **NOT** rerun.

Here are two examples to illustrate what's happening.

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  post: function () {
    var someReactiveVar = Session.get('value');

    return Posts.findOne({_id: 5});
  }
});
```

In the above example, a change to post 5, or to Session's value will trigger the template to re-run. Let's say we want the template to re-run only for changes to the post, but not for the session variable. We could do this:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  post: function () {
    var someNonReactiveVar = Deps.nonreactive(function () { return Session.get('value'); });

    return Post.findOne({_id: 5});
  }
});
```

Now, just because we call Session.set('value', 'some other value') the template will not be re-run because we wrapped the get call inside a Deps.nonreactive callback.

Comment: I didn't realize that `Session` variables were magic and changing them would make Meteor update. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the answer to this question? Sounds like what you are looking for

[Meteor.js - temporarily prevent a template from re-rendering (disable reactivity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033828/meteor-js-temporarily-prevent-a-template-from-re-rendering-disable-reactivity)

Comment: I don't want to turn off reactivity completely, just stop one function from triggering it.