# Meteor: Prevent template from re-rendering

Tags: javascript, meteor, rendering, handlebars.js

So I have a page which displays some data (questions) coming from a collection in a ul.

[Link to example](http://questfultest.meteor.com/server1/559Gy) (feel free to fiddle around, it's just sample data!)

If the user clicks on the button in the bottom right a previously hidden div is shown with a textarea so the user can post a new question. That all works fine. Problem is that if a new question is posted from another user while the user is typing a new question, this user gets thrown back into the "questions view" because the ul is rerendered because of the new entry.

What I want is that the user, who is currently typing a new question, does NOT instanly see the new question so he can continue typing in the textarea in the div. --> What I need is a way to prevent the ul (its template) from rerendering.

I tried `{{#constant}}` and all that stuff + had a look into [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033828/meteor-js-temporarily-prevent-a-template-from-re-rendering-disable-reactivity) but it can't get it to work.

What I need is a way to prevent the rerendering onclick of the "post a question" button and of course a way to continue rerendering after the question is posted and the textarea + its div is hidden again.

I hope you guys can help! thx!

best regards P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's not necessary to wait with rendering the new question, since the dialog is opaque anyway, so it won't be a difference to the user. You need only to make sure that the dialog itself will not be rendered.

There are three ways to achieve it:

- Put **dialog** only in `{{#constant}}` block.
- Put **dialog** and **question list** to separate `{{#isolate}}` blocks.
- Put dialog and list in separate **templates.** That's the most robust and thus recommended method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `{{#isolate}}` thingy did the job! Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting unique ids on your questions:

id="question_{{_id}}"

Then meteor can be smarter about what it is updating.